# How to save Netbeans search results to a file?

Tags: search, netbeans, save

I did a search in NB for all of my *.java programs that contains a certain string, and got a list of a few dozen programs in the search result panel, how to save the result to a text file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you've done your search, there is a button on the left that says "See All Details" when you hover over it. Click that. You will see the text version of the search results. Inside that text result panel you can hit `CTRL-S` or right click and save the results to a file of your choice.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for, but in a not so obvious way. It will be more intuitive if I can right mouse click on the search results panel and select "save as ..." or "save to file", isn't that the way how most windows app handles it ?